# Wordpress woocommerce - Creating order at payment/checkout process

Tags: woocommerce, payment-gateway, payment

I am using woocommerce plugin version 2.6.14.

Whenever customer initiates a payment process (via PayPal) to deposit funds in the wallet, a new order is created whose email is sent to both customer and admin. Now, this order's email will confuse the customer because such order has not been created. For the customer, this is a simple add funds process.

I found this URL but I dont know how to resolve this issue in my code.
[Woocommerce checkout process creating new order at payment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370911/woocommerce-checkout-process-creating-new-order-at-payment)

Please help.